# Passing NULL value into parameterized delphi SQL server query

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe4, parameterized-query

I am trying to pass in a null value to a TSQLDataset parameter. The query has the form:

```
Query_text:='MERGE INTO [Table] 
             USING (VALUES (:A,:B)) AS Source (Source_A, Source_B)
             ....
             WHEN MATCHED THEN 
             UPDATE SET A = :A
             WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
             INSERT(A, B) VALUES (:A,:B);

SQL_dataset.CommandType:=ctQuery; 
SQL_dataset.CommandText:=Query_text;

SQL_dataset.ParamByName('A').AsString:='A';  
SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').AsString:={ COULD BE NULL, OR A STRING };    

SQL_dataset.ExecSQL;
```

Parameter B is nullable, but is also a foreign key. If the user enters something in this field, then B must be validated against values in another table. If it is blank then I want it to be ignored. I was passing in '', but this obviously produces a FK violation error.

I tried:

```
SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').Value:=Null;
```

..but then I get a "dbexpress driver does not support the tdbxtypes.unknown data type" error.

I also tried:

```
SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').DataType:=ftVariant;
SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').Value:=Null;
```

..but then got "dbexpress driver does not support the tdbxtypes.variant data type" error.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. I am currently drawing up a parameter list based on whether the string is populated or not, and this works well; it's just a bit clunky (in my actual query) as there are quite a few parameters to validate.

I am using Delphi XE4 and SQL server 2012.

**Update:**

Thanks for all the help, your suggestions were right all along, it was something else that produced that 'dbexpress driver' error. I was creating a 'flexible' parameter list in an effort to get around my problem, and this caused the exception:

```
Parameter_string:='';

If B<>'' then Parameter_string:='B = :B,'

Query_text:='MERGE ...'
            '...'
            'UPDATE SET A = :A, '+Parameter_string+' C = :C' ....
```

... the idea being that if B is blank then the parameter won't be 'listed' in the query.

This doesn't work, or my implementation of it doesn't work (not sure why, I'm obviously missing a step somewhere).

Anyway, the working code:

```
Query_text:='MERGE ...'
            '...'
            'UPDATE SET A = :A, B = :B, C = :C' ....

SQL_dataset.CommandType:=ctQuery; 
SQL_dataset.CommandText:=Query_text;

If B<>'' then
begin
  SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').AsString:='B';
end
else
begin
  SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').DataType:=ftString;
  SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').Value:=Null;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

what about:

`SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').Clear;`

Comment: I had read that suggestion elsewhere, but I get the "dbExpress driver does not support the TDBXTypes.UNKNOWN data type.  Vendor error message:" error when I try that. Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Strange... currently I'm migrating from FIB+ to FireDAC and I tested it on both connectivities and it is possible to use either Clear or Value := null assignment. And I'd expect that it works on each dataset. At least I've never met a problem with this, but I never used dbExpress.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the db-null equivalent in Delphi is Variants.Null

Answer (score 0):

Usual approach would be using parameters once per query and assign the appropriate datatype.
Value may be assigned to NULL.

```
var
 Query_text:String;
begin
  Query_text:='Declare @A varchar(100) ' // or e.g. integer
       +#13#10'Declare @B varchar(100)'  
       +#13#10'Select @A=:A'
       +#13#10'Select @B=:B'
       +#13#10'Update Adressen Set Vorname=@A,Strasse=@B where Name=@B';
  SQL_dataset.CommandType := ctQuery;
  SQL_dataset.CommandText := Query_text;
  SQL_dataset.Params.ParseSQL(SQL_dataset.CommandText,true);
  Showmessage(IntToStr(SQL_dataset.Params.Count));
  SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').DataType := ftString;
  SQL_dataset.ParamByName('B').Value := 'MyText';
  SQL_dataset.ParamByName('A').DataType := ftString;  // or e.g. ftInteger
  SQL_dataset.ParamByName('A').Value := NULL;
  SQL_dataset.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, get same error as noted above in comment to @pf1957. Mayve I have something else that's casung this error?

Comment: in my experiance this is the correct way for xe series.